# JNIEnv usage with or without parenthasis?

Tags: android, c++, c, pointers, java-native-interface

I am curious why the [jni programming guide](http://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/cpp.html) said

> The JNI provides a slightly cleaner interface for C++ programmers. The
>   `jni.h` file contains a set of inline C++ functions so that the native
>   method programmer can simply write:
>
> ```
> jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
> ```
>
> The extra level of indirection on `env` and the `env` argument to
>   `FindClass` are hidden from the programmer. The C++ compiler simply
>   expands out the C++ member function calls to their C counterparts;
>   therefore, the resulting code is exactly the same.

What is the difference between c and c++ pointers?

Comment: **Don't** use pictures for text.

Comment: @Deduplicator and why is that? I just want to show the example of my question.

Comment: @tonylin please take your time to `key in` the lines. makes more readable.

Comment: Because while it may look good enough for you, it is a) not searchable, b) does not scale properly, c) means extra bandwidth and delay, and d) some clients won't show it *at all* (or at least in acceptable size).

Comment: @Deduplicator Ok. I know and I will edit my question next time. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `C++` pointer is a pointer to a class `object`. The `C` pointer is a pointer to a `function`. They are two different things.

Because the `C++ object` already knows the environment, you do not need to pass the environment again.

The `C` pointer is a pointer to a struct, and in that struct you call the function. The function has no state, so you need to pass the state (in this case, the same `env` struct, so it can find the variables in this struct.).

In `jni.h` in the `JDK` you see that the `C++` function is:

```
jclass FindClass(const char *name) {
    return functions->FindClass(this, name);
}
```

And that `functions` is a pointer inside the object that points to the `env`. So the `C++` version internally expands to the `C` version.